# Invalid object name 'sys.dm_os_volume_stats'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dmv

I am trying to select 15% of disk space available in a server.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
            s.volume_mount_point [Drive],
            CAST(s.available_bytes / 1048576.0 as decimal(20,2)) [AvailableMBs],
           ((CAST(s.total_bytes / 1048576.0 as decimal(20,2)))*15)/100 AS [FifteenpercentAvailableMBs]  

            FROM 
                    sys.master_files f
                    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.[file_id]) s
```

This query works well in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

But it wont work in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)

How can I make this query work in 2008 R2 RTM? (I mean is there any alternative query that I can use to get 15% of available space?)

Comment: Why are you still running RTM? dm_os_volume_stats was introduced in SP1

Comment: we have some old servers we still need to support.

Comment: That's not really a reason to still be using RTM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use this DMV in RTM; it was introduced in SP1 (though [the current version of the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223223.aspx) does not specify that, [the 2008 R2 version does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223223(v=sql.105).aspx)). You should be on [Service Pack 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44271) anyway (that will make those old servers *easier* to support, not harder).

In RTM you can do some really convoluted things, [like this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2444/script-to-get-available-and-free-disk-space-for-sql-server/). He is using `xp_cmdshell` to call PowerShell to grab output from a WMI class (`Win32_Volume`), then dump those results into a #temp table, and compare them to data from an undocumented and unsupported extended procedure, `xp_fixeddrives`.

There is [a similar solution here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2929/monitoring-sql-server-disk-space/). It uses WMI (`Win32_PhysicalDisk`), VBScript, and PowerShell from a SQL Server Agent job - while they avoid `xp_cmdshell` here, the overall methodology feels similarly hobbled together.

If you were working in construction, these would be the equivalent of about eight rolls of duct tape and a half gallon of WD-40.

Maybe you should consider performing this task using PowerShell or similar ([doesn't this seem a lot simpler](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3109/monitor-sql-server-disk-space-using-powershell/)?), instead of trying to bend T-SQL to do this. SQL Server isn't really the right tool to manage server disk space.

Comment: I just signed up to vote you up ...  "If you were working in construction, these would be the equivalent of about eight rolls of duct tape and a half gallon of WD-40." ... it made my day :)